# Angularjs converting jquery plugin to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use [this](http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/) in an angularjs and am putting it into a directive.  The problem I encountered is that I have to 'double click' when a checkbox is defaulted to being checked.  This doesn't happen when used natively outside of the directive, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the directive.

Here's the code I have, is there anything that seems out of place or missing for a directive?

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('ccCheckbox', function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict:'A',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

            elm.iphoneStyle({
                checkedLabel : attrs.ccCheckboxChecked,
                uncheckedLabel : attrs.ccCheckboxUnChecked,
                onChange: function(elem, value) {
                    controller.$setViewValue(value);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is the markup I'm using:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="users.online" cc-checkbox cc-checkbox-checked="Online" cc-checkbox-unchecked="Offline" checked="checked">
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that you need to call $setViewValue to load the initial value from the DOM.  On the [forms page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), see the script.js tab for the last example:  it calls `ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html())` in the linking function.  You probably need to do something like that.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like it could be right, tried it but didn't work.  It's actually an intermittent problem, sometimes it changes first click, other times it doesn't.

Comment: Instead of `elm.html()` (which maybe isn't always set when you initially call `$setViewValue()`), try setting the initial view value based on the value of `attrs.checked`.